# Select multiple columns for AutoComplete result using LinQ

Tags: linq, .net-core, autocomplete

I'm setting up an AutoComplete function that will return a list of Holdings with associated Codes. (e.g. Google GOOGL, Amazon AMZ, etc)

I am able to get the results using the following code:

```
var names = _context.UMA
            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(term) || p.Code.Contains(term))
            .Select(p => p.Name );
```

This code works and returns a list of Holding Names.
I now want to add the Holding Codes in the result.

I changed the last line of Code to this:

```
.Select(p => new {p.Code, p.Name})
```

But the result only shows blank lines (but the correct number of blank lines.)

If I change the last line to just this:

```
.Select(p => new { p.Name})
```

I still get blank lines (and, yes, correct number of blank lines.)

Any help always appreciated!

Comment: How do yo see these blank lines? Does `names.ToList()` from debug contains results or only empty strings? I guess that you have some problem with printing these results because your code should work fine.

Comment: Your code is correct. As @Dejan suggested, it should be the problem with how you are displaying the output.

Comment: Thanks fellas, it does seem like the problem lies with the result display.